# Regex that matches a pattern but does not match ":"

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex that looks for certain types of hostnames like: `.*-.*(nmtg)*|.*(\.nms)`. How do I modify this so it does not match: `11.22:33:44:55-66`?

Should match:

```
cs25-admin.nmtg.company.com 
cs25-admin
```

but should not match:

```
11.22:33:44:55-66
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output for the matches. Also, what is the regex you are using? `/.*-.*(com)*|.*(\.org)/`?

Answer (score 3):

Two basic ways:

- You can replace your "match anything" `.` with "match anything except for colon" `[^:]` everywhere
- You can prepend your expression with "no colons from here to the end of string" `(?!.*:)`

**EDIT** As Signus said, your regexp is really non-specific and open-ended; it will match much more than what you think. For example, `"----THRICEnmtgnmtgnmtg"` is a full match, and so is `"(-_-)"`. It is a better policy and easier to carefully specify what you want, rather than go listing exceptions. The regexps suggested by Signus are a good example.

They will still match within strings: `"dont match this: example.com"` will still match the `"example.com"` part. If that is what you want, cool. If not, you want to anchor the start and end of the string, by surrounding your regexp with `/^.....$/`.

Comment: Is it something like this .[^:]*-.[^:]*(com)*|.[^:]*(\.org)

Comment: (?!.*:).*-.*(com)*|.*(\.org)

Comment: both seem to match the last two bits 55-66

Comment: Of course they do. There's no colons there. If you want to disallow partial matches, you need to anchor the ends to something. But since you didn't provide any positive examples and only one negative example, nor said if you want to match it in a larger string or not, I can't say much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `*` quantifier that matches 0 or more of the preceding token, in which case you supplied `.` which is a token that matches any character except line breaks.

To match domain names with subdomain names you can do the following:

```
(\w+\.)?\w+\.(com|org)
```

And to really match any domain with a TLD I like to do this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.){1,2}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

Where the latter will match any domain with a single subdomain using the numeric quantifer `{num}` which allows you to specify a range of matches, as shown in the above regex.

This allows you to match a group of alphanumeric characters followed by a period 1 to 2 times (i.e. subdomain.domain.topleveldomain, where `subdomain.` is the first match and `domain.` is the second match of the first group).